# angular/typescript: async subscription not returning as expected

Tags: typescript

I'm sure that the issue is that I'm a noob and don't completely understand the fundamentals of async/await.

I have two functions: one returns an object and one returns an array (shown below).

- The one that returns an Object returns as expected.
- The one that returns an array returns `undefined`.

What is the difference that is causing the hang-up?

---

#### userRole.service.ts

```
async getUserRolesEnum(): Promise<any> {
    var result: any = {};

    await this.authHttp
      .get<UserRole[]>(this.baseUrl + "UserRoles", { headers: this.httpOptions.headers }).subscribe((data: UserRole[]) => {
        data.forEach(p => result[p.role] = p.id);
      });

    console.log("enum after subscription");
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}

async getUserRolesArray(): Promise<UserRole[]> {
    var result: UserRole[];

    await this.authHttp
      .get<UserRole[]>(this.baseUrl + "UserRoles", { headers: this.httpOptions.headers }).subscribe((data: UserRole[]) => {
        result = data;
        console.log("array within subscription:");
        console.log(result);
      });

    console.log("array after subscription:");
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

#### Chrome console at runtime:

[image]

Comment: `subscribe` is used with observables, and `then` is used with promises.

Comment: async/await is not compatible with observables

Comment: I have the same issue if I remove the promise, async, and await decorators. So it must not be an async/await issue.

Comment: But it's still definitely an issue.

Comment: If you remove async/await & promise, this issue will persist because of asynchronous behavior of observable.

Comment: So, any idea what the issue even is? Why can I return an Object but not an array (with basically the same function)

Comment: It works if I do `.subscribe((data: UserRole[]) => { data.forEach(p => result.push(p));});`

Comment: Did you tried `enum within subscription`?

Comment: I can log the enum from within the subscription

Comment: Check out my answer, and the link provided in it. It explains the behaviour in case of looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async/Await only works with Promises, **not** with RxJS Observables, `subscribe` works with observable, & `then` works with promises.

Here, both API calls works as observable. If you want Async/Await to work with Obervable, you should subscribe to an observable with **`forEach`** to create concurrent tasks in Async/Await. As shown here,

[Subscribe to an Observable with forEach](https://gist.github.com/benlesh/6ea17efa795b1b40820c0fba004d4c84#file-example4-js)

Here, when you subscribe to Objects, you are using forEach on response variable, So, Subscribed response data got treated, or I should say resubscribed via forEach, and it worked as per the rules shown in the link above.

It also explains you query in comments on the question. Question was => Why does is work when I do `data.forEach(p => result.push(p))` instead of `result = data` in case of array subscription?

Promises are used to subscribe to single instance of data, while observables for multiple data. Async/Await, as for now, works for single data only. When you use forEach looping, all those multiple instances of response data get subscribes one by one in may be promise fashion, or similar to it, depending on inner implementation. But simple subscription doesn't do that.

Just like promises, if you subscribe observable using forEach, they are not cancellable too.

Also, Even if it worked in this way. It would be recommended to use Async/Await with Promises, **or** Use forEach Subscription just as shown in the link to avoid any bug to emerge after any future updates.